# Is there any incentive to play Junkenstein's Revenge on harder difficulties?

Tags: overwatch

The Halloween event Junkenstein's Revenge has three difficulty options to choose from - easy, medium, and hard. Aside from playing at a level that feels challenging enough to be enjoyable, is there any reward difference (EXP or other unlockables) that would encourage playing at higher difficulties?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to play beyond Hard mode.

There are achievements for beating Junkenstein's Revenge for:

- Beating medium (Junkenstein's Revenge spray)
- Beating medium without any damage to the door (The Reapening spray)
- Beating hard (Halloween Special spray)
- Beating it using every hero once. (Rise of the Zomnics spray)

Each achievement of course has its own spray tied to it as a reward for gaining the achievement./

EXP is usually doled out by time played, and since typical Junkenstein matches take 6 - 8 minutes, I get roughly 2 - 2.2k exp.  I tested this across easy, medium, and hard, and found no difference in EXP gain (completed all 3 modes).

Comment: Is there also a difference in maximum score? I notice when I play on easy, there are 2 lock symbols next to the stars, but some of my friends only have 1. Does this indicate they were playing on medium?

Comment: @Unionhawk I don't have any proof since I only played medium so far, but I suspect that available stars are locked based on difficulty. On easy mode two stars are locked (making 3 stars the highest score you can get), medium has one star locked, and hard has all stars unlocked.

Comment: Do you get (any of) these in PS4?  I have beaten easy and medium and I don't believe I received any awards.